# Showing that a certain operator maps to $\mathscr{C}([0,1])$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, integral-operators

I'm considering the operator $T$ given by (Tf)(x)=$\int_0^1k(x,y)f(y)dy$ with $dom(T)=\mathrm{L}^1([0,1])$, where $k\in\mathscr{C}([0,1]^2)$ and want to proof that it maps to $\mathscr{C}([0,1])$.

I know that for a given $x\in[0,1]$ and $\varepsilon>0$ the continuity of k gives me:$$\forall y\in[0,1]\exists\delta_y>0:\forall z\in[0,1]:\lvert x-z\rvert\lt\delta_y\implies\lvert k(x,y)-k(z,y)\rvert\lt\frac{\varepsilon}{\lvert\lvert f\rvert\rvert_1}$$
and also for any given $z$
$$\lvert(Tf)(x)-(Tf)(z)\rvert \le max_{y\in[0,1]}\lvert k(x,y)-k(z,y)\lvert\cdot\lvert\lvert f\rvert\rvert_1\le\lvert k(x,y_{max}-k(z,y_{max})\rvert\cdot\lvert\lvert f\rvert\rvert_{1}$$
but to prove continuity of $Tf$ I have to chose a $\delta$ before I can pick a $z$, I would expect that maybe $\sup_{[0,1]}\delta_y$ suffices, but then I would first have to show that it is finite?

Any hint is very welcome.

Comment: you in effect want to pass a limit across an integral sign: how about using dominated convergence? $k<=M$ for some $M$, so $|kf| \le M|f|$.

Comment: The uniform continuity of $k$ says that you can choose $\delta$ independent of $y$.

Comment: Typo in my suggestion - I forgot to pu the abs. values in $|k|\le M$....  Daniel's suggestion is more direct anyway.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thank you. Can I use the uniform continuity 'on the way' though? I think I once proved the same claim for a similar operator by explicitly applying compactness of [0,1] and continuity of k in each component. I know this is equivalent to just using the uniform continuity but I would like to remember how i did it.

Comment: I don't understand what you're aiming at. The separate continuity of $k$ is not sufficient to get the result. (If you add boundedness, you get that continuity of $Tf$ from dominated convergence.)

Comment: I thought I could prove it using continuity of $k(x,\cdot)$ for any x and compactness of [0,1] first and the continuity of $k(\cdot,y)$ for any y again with compactness of [0,1] later. Both times applying that these functions assume their maxima or something along these lines.